# Style to keep the text aligned when wrapped

Tags: css

```css
.has-parent:not(.has-children):before {
    padding-right: 0.25em;
    content: "\0007C";
    font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-parent" style="padding-left: 1em;">
  Component 6
</div>
```

I have text that wraps on to the next line. When wrapped to the next line, I want the text to align instead of moving under a span. The image below shows the problem that I am facing.

[image]

In the above image, I want 6 to align under C. I don't have control over the layout. I can modify the CSS to get the desired effect. The layout of the cell is below.

```
<div class="has-parent" style="padding-left: 1em;">
  Component 6
</div>
```

The | that you are seeing is from CSS:

```
.has-parent:not(.has-children):before {
    padding-right: 0.25em;
    content: "\0007C";
    font-size: large;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on parent element.

```css
.has-parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
}

.has-parent:not(.has-children):before {
  padding-right: 0.25em;
  content: "\0007C";
}
```

```html
<div class="has-parent" style="padding-left: 1em;">
  Component 6
</div>
```

Comment: Added align-items: center to the parent element for centering. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: absolute` for `.has-parent:not(.has-children):before` and play with margin and padding.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wh9uq5m1/)

```css
.has-parent {
  padding: 0.1em 0 0 1.5em;
}

.has-parent:not(.has-children):before {
    content: "\0007C";
    font-size: large;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -0.1em 0 0 -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-parent">
  Component 6
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float: left` for `.has-parent:not(.has-children):before`
that should do the job

Answer (score 0):

```css
.has-parent:not(.has-children):before {
    padding-right: 0.25em;
    content: "\0007C";
    font-size: large;
}

span {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:142px){
  span {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="has-parent" style="padding-left: 1em;">
  Component <span>6</span>
</div>
```

Change the @media query to whatever screen-size you need.